# Using push_back on a vector<vector<string> >

Tags: c++, stl

I'm somewhat embarrassed that such a simple problem has stymied me, but after a few hours of fruitless googling, I'm still stuck.

To simplify my problem, the 2nd line of this crashes:

```
  vector<vector<string> > sorted_words;
  sorted_words[0].push_back("hello");
```

Shouldn't `sorted_words[0]` represent an empty vector that I can legally push_back onto?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  You have a vector of vectors.  You haven't added anything to either vector by line 2, so `sorted_words[0]`, the first element in `sorted_words`, doesn't exist yet.

You're trying to push `"hello"` into a null `vector`.

Null pointer dereference!

I would ask "do you really want a vector of vectors, or just a vector of strings"?

If you want a vector of strings, then use:

```
vector<string> sorted_words;
sorted_words.push_back("hello");
```

If you really do want a vector of vectors (of strings), then use:

```
vector<string> first_vector;
first_vector.push_back("hello");
sorted_words.push_back(first_vector);
```

Comment: That makes sense.  What I'm trying to to do is take map<string, int> of words & word counts, and reverse it.  (So I have a count & the list of words that show that often.)  My original code is more like:   `for (map<string, int>::const_iterator it = counters.begin();
       it != counters.end(); ++it) { sorted_words[ it->second ].push_back( it->first ); }`

Comment: @TheyCallMeBruce, ok, so does this explanation solve your problem, or do you still have questions?  Perhaps a new question that explains the entire problem you're trying to solve might be useful?

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

Your object sorted_words is a vector of vectors.

```
vector<vector<string>> sorted_words;
if (sorted_words.empty()) {
  sorted_words.resize(1);
}
sorted_words[0].emplace_back("Hello");
```

In general, accession through operator to a vector has the implicit precondition that the vector has a size greater than i.

Answer (score 0):

Your `sorted_words` has not been allocated memory. so `sorted_words[0]` will try to access something that does not exist yet.

try the following:

```
 vector<vector<string> > sorted_words (100);
 sorted_words[0].push_back("Hello");
```

Or you can do the following:

```
 vector<vector<string> > sorted_words;
 vector<string> innerVec;
 innerVec.push_back("Hello");
 innerVec.push_back("World");
 sorted_words.push_back(innerVec);
```

You can view a live example here: http://ideone.com/KlliR8#view_edit_box

Comment: Instead of `vector<vector<string>>` you could use `queue<vector<string>>`, see:

`queue<vector<string>> sorted_words;  sorted_words.push_back({ "hello" });`