# Reverse a mapping of map<string, int> to vector<vector<string> >

Tags: c++, stl

Building on my [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16258711), I have a mapping of words & their counts stored in a `map<string, int>`.  I want to reverse that, so that all the words with the same count are group together.  My solution was to use a `vector<vector<string> >`.  The index of the first vector being the count & the 2nd vector being the collection for words.

After reading the answers to the prior question, here what I've been trying to make work:

```
  vector<vector<string> > sorted_words;
    for (map<string, int>::const_iterator it = counters.begin();
       it != counters.end(); ++it) {
    cout << "word:" << it->first
         << " count:" << it-> second
         << " vector size: " << sorted_words.size()
         << endl;

    if (sorted_words.size() - 1 > it->second && 
        sorted_words[ it->second ].size() > 0) {
      cout << "Adding " << it->first << endl;
      sorted_words[ it->second ].push_back(it->first);
    } else {
      cout << "Creating " << it->first << endl;
      vector<string> v;
      v.push_back(it->first);
      sorted_words.resize( it->second + 1 );
      sorted_words[it->second] = v;
    }
  }
```

This results in a segfault on the very first pass of the loop, at the if statement.

What I'm trying to do is see if the outer vector is sized such that my current value is inbounds & if so, if I've already created a nested vector.  (I need to do this, because the map can come back in any order.  E.g., the very first element could be <"foo", 3>.)

If I'm going about it in a fundamentally non-C++ way, feel free to point that as well.

Comment: `map<int, vector<string> >` is one way to do so.

Comment: So fundamentally I'm going down the wrong road trying to use vector<vector<string>>?

Comment: Depends: if the most indexes are full (i.e. there are words of size 1, 2, 3, ...) then vector<vector<string>> is good if not map is the better option.

Comment: The problem with vector-of-vectors is that your outer vector seems likely to be sparse--what if you have a couple words that occur thousands of times, but no words that occur between 100 and 1000 times?  You'll have 900 useless vectors inside!

Comment: You could use a [`std::multimap<int, std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap), though I prefer `std::map<int, std::vector<std::string>>` personally.

Comment: In general case, it is not possible to know whether the indices are full or not, since it depends on the data. Both `vector` and `map` are OK for small cases of 1000 or 10000 strings, beyond that, I expect the problem of storing the strings in memory outweights the problem of which data structure to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick wild ass guess:  `sorted_words.size()` is some unsigned type (namely `size_t`) so `sorted_words.size() - 1` is unsigned even when it should be -1 (initially) thus you always pass the first condition and the second half of the if condition evaluates and crashes.

Answer (score 3):

For space, you would be likely better served to use a `std::map<int, std::vector<string>>`. The following rather trivial code (which could be improved by lower-casing all the words and stripping punctuation) demonstrates:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // map of strings to counts.
    std::map<string, int> strs;
    ifstream inf(argv[1]);
    string str;
    while (inf >> str)
        ++strs[str];

    // map of counts to strings, smallest to largest.
    std::map<int, std::vector<string>> vals;
    for (auto it : strs)
        vals[ it.second ].push_back(it.first);

    // report counts for each
    for (auto it : vals)
    {
        cout << "Count: " << it.first << ": ";
        std::copy(it.second.begin(), it.second.end(),
                  ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " "));
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

**Sample Input**

I chose a monologue from W. Shakespeare's "As You Like It", which has some interesting attributes, as you will see in a moment:

```
All the world's a stage,
And all the men and women merely players:
They have their exits and their entrances;
And one man in his time plays many parts,
His acts being seven ages. At first, the infant,
Mewling and puking in the nurse's arms.
And then the whining school-boy, with his satchel
And shining morning face, creeping like snail
Unwillingly to school. And then the lover,
Sighing like furnace, with a woeful ballad
Made to his mistress' eyebrow. Then a soldier,
Full of strange oaths and bearded like the pard,
Jealous in honour, sudden and quick in quarrel,
Seeking the bubble reputation
Even in the cannon's mouth. And then the justice,
In fair round belly with good capon lined,
With eyes severe and beard of formal cut,
Full of wise saws and modern instances;
And so he plays his part. The sixth age shifts
Into the lean and slipper'd pantaloon,
With spectacles on nose and pouch on side,
His youthful hose, well saved, a world too wide
For his shrunk shank; and his big manly voice,
Turning again toward childish treble, pipes
And whistles in his sound. Last scene of all,
That ends this strange eventful history,
Is second childishness and mere oblivion,
Sans teeth, sans eyes, sans taste, sans everything.
```

**Sample Output**

```
 Count: 1: All At Even For In Into Is Jealous Last Made Mewling Sans Seeking Sighing That The Then They Turning Unwillingly acts again age ages. all all, arms. ballad beard bearded being belly big bubble cannon's capon childish childishness creeping cut, ends entrances; eventful everything. exits eyebrow. eyes eyes, face, fair first, formal furnace, good have he history, honour, hose, infant, instances; justice, lean lined, lover, man manly many men mere merely mistress' modern morning mouth. nose nurse's oaths oblivion, one pantaloon, pard, part. parts, pipes players: pouch puking quarrel, quick reputation round satchel saved, saws scene school-boy, school. second seven severe shank; shifts shining shrunk side, sixth slipper'd snail so soldier, sound. spectacles stage, sudden taste, teeth, this time too toward treble, voice, well whining whistles wide wise woeful women world world's youthful 
 Count: 2: Full His With on plays strange their to 
 Count: 3: like sans then with 
 Count: 4: a of 
 Count: 6: in 
 Count: 7: his 
 Count: 8: And 
 Count: 11: and the
```

Interesting the number of unique word-strings in a monologue that large. Almost like he planned it that way. However, the numbers are notably different when accounting for capitalization and punctuation removal. Thankfully, it was trivial to do that as well, changing only the first while-loop:

```
while (inf >> str)
{
    string alpha;
    for_each(str.begin(), str.end(),
            [](char& c){c=tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));});
    copy_if(str.begin(), str.end(), back_inserter(alpha),
            [](const char& c){return isalpha(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));});
    ++strs[alpha];
}
```

This gave us the following results:

```
 Count: 1: acts again age ages arms at ballad beard bearded being belly big bubble cannons capon childish childishness creeping cut ends entrances even eventful everything exits eyebrow face fair first for formal furnace good have he history honour hose infant instances into is jealous justice last lean lined lover made man manly many men mere merely mewling mistress modern morning mouth nose nurses oaths oblivion one pantaloon pard part parts pipes players pouch puking quarrel quick reputation round satchel saved saws scene school schoolboy second seeking seven severe shank shifts shining shrunk side sighing sixth slipperd snail so soldier sound spectacles stage sudden taste teeth that they this time too toward treble turning unwillingly voice well whining whistles wide wise woeful women world worlds youthful 
 Count: 2: eyes full on plays strange their to 
 Count: 3: all like 
 Count: 4: a of sans then 
 Count: 5: with 
 Count: 7: in 
 Count: 9: his 
 Count: 12: the 
 Count: 19: and
```

Still, pretty impressive, Billy.

As an added bonus due to the nature of the first map sorting you get the resulting word lists in per-count alphabetical order. Woot for bonus features.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invert a `map<K, V>`, use a `map<V, vector<K>>`. If you don’t care about what the actual count is at that point, you can build the `vector<vector<V>>` efficiently by moving from the intermediate map. For example:

```
vector<vector<string>> invert(const map<string, int>& input) {

  map<int, vector<string>> inverse;
  for (const auto& pair : input)
    inverse[pair.second].push_back(pair.first);

  vector<vector<string>> result;
  for (auto& pair : inverse)
    result.push_back(move(pair.second));

  return result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a `vector<vector<string>>` or an inverted map like `map<int, vector>`, you can utilize the map (`map<string, int>`) you already have and just create a `vector<vector<int>>` to collect the *indices* of all the words having the same count. This will save you a lot of space. Also, when you modify your previous `map<string, int>` all you need to do is update the indices in `vector<vector<int>>` which will be faster than in other two approaches.